# Angular JS on AWS cannot deploy on unique domain address

Tags: angular, amazon-s3

I have gone through all my steps for registering my angular app on AWS! I have a unique domain and I am still encountering issues with deploying the app? I am able to deploy it over the AWS modified domain which is not my unique domain. I receive 404 errors or service is no longer available etc. Is there any good website that describes this process for angular js ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out myself. AWS Ampilfy was able to fix my domain and deploy my angulur js app successfully! Creating just a pipeline did not work for me!